# axios in React isnt sending info to Express server (Files uplaod)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, axios, multipartform-data

Hi so i have a React client and a Express Server, so the problem is that when i try to send info from the React client to the Express Server it doesn't arrive I have tried to approches .

**First One**

Without FormData .

houseService.js

```
export const addHouse = (House) => {
  axios.post('/api/properties/houses/createHouse', House).then(res => console.log(res.data))
}
```

This Sends the data to the Express Server but images fails to arrive .
Here the JSON .

```
{ name: 'Nombre Prueba',
  address: 
   { street: 'Calle Prueba',
     ext_number: 1,
     int_number: 1,
     colony: 'Colonia Prueba',
     postal_code: 95264,
     city: 'Ciudad Prueba',
     municipality: 'Municipio Prueba',
     state: 'Estado Prueba',
     location: [ 1, 2 ] },
  characteristics: { room: 1, parking: 1, bathroom: 1, half_bathroom: 1 },
  size: { built: 1, total: 1 },
  services: [ 'Gas' ],
  amenities: [ 'Estudio' ],
  retail: 'Renta',
  antiquity: 1,
  status: 'Terminada',
  user: '5b109656f869730ed45460af',
  photos: [ { file: {} } ] }
```

But as we can see photos is empty, if i print photos in the react client side it will print the object.

**Second One**

With FormData

housesService.js

```
export const addHouse = (House) => {
    let data = new FormData()

    for (let key in House) {
        data.append(key, House[key])
    }
    axios.post('/api/properties/houses/createHouse', data, {
        headers: {
            'accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${data._boundary}`,
        }
    }).then(res => console.log(res.data))
```

When trying to get the data from this on the server side nothing appears, it shows a empty JSON .

```
this.state = {
      name : 'Nombre Prueba',
      street : 'Calle Prueba',
      ext_number : 1,
      int_number : 1,
      colony : 'Colonia Prueba',
      postal_code : 95264,
      city : 'Ciudad Prueba',
      municipality : 'Municipio Prueba',
      state : 'Estado Prueba',
      location : [1,2],
      room : 1,
      parking : 1,
      bathroom : 1,
      half_bathroom : 1,
      services : ['Gas'],
      amenities : ['Estudio'],
      built : 1,
      total : 1,
      retail : 'Renta',
      antiquity : 1,
      status : 'Terminada',
      user : '5b109656f869730ed45460af',
      photos : [],
      submitted: false,
    };
```

I uplaod photos with .

```
<div className="field-wrap">
              <input type="file"
              name="photos"
              onChange={this._handleImageChange}
              className={submitted && !photos ?
                  "invalid" : ""
                }
              multiple/>
            </div>
```

I can print the photo with console log before de AXIOS

Comment: What are you passing to the function in the `House` param?

Comment: @wdm check, i just edited it

Comment: @joserh94 Could you plz add your server code that creates the app? Have you configured a middleware (say `multer` or whatever) to parse multipart body content? `body-parser` does not handle multipart bodies.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko let me double check with my teammates, might be tomorrow my answer tho, ill check it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the photos array and append each photo separately. Try this code:

```
export const addHouse = House => {
    let data = new FormData();

    for (const key of House) {
        if (key !== 'photos') {
            data.append(key, House[key]);
        }
    }
    for (const photo of House['photos']) {
        data.append('photos', photo);
    }
    axios.post('/api/properties/houses/createHouse', data)
        .then(res => console.log(res.data));
}
```

Comment: i couldnt use of so i changed it for in, still body arrives empty, but in inspect >> network on browser i think we are getting the photos they are just not arriving

Comment: So i printed console.log('photos', photo) and it printed a 0 so i tried with House[photo] and it printed undefined also tried console.log('photos', photo.file) and undefined, console.log('photos', photo.name) and undefined @wdm

Comment: This code assumes that your photos when uploaded are stored in `this.state.photos` and that you're passing the `state` as the `House` param of you're `addHouse` function. I have a similar setup working in a live application so double check to make sure.

Comment: thanks, let me check i might have to check it tomorrow tho, kinda late here, could it be that addHouse is beeing call in a reducer and not in the react where the state is? i send the state to a reducer file and in there i call the function